# Vectorise this R loop and custom function

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

I have a `data.frame` with scores in named columns, I need to get `rowMeans` of certain clusters of columns as per an index file that defines which `colNames` need to be grouped. I'd like to do this simultaneously, as it is currently done in a loop that passes in the current 'cluster' to work on. See below.

I have two data frames, one is an index file with the following (plus much more, this is obv just for example)

```
set.seed(42)
index <- data.frame(area=c("area1","area1","area1","area2","area2","area2","area1",
    "area1","area4","area5"), name=c(paste0("name",sample(6,10,replace=T))))
```

The other is a data file, again here is an impoverished example

```
data <- data.frame(name1=sample(10,5),name2=sample(10,5),name3=sample(10,5),
       name4=sample(10,5),name5=sample(10,5),name6=sample(10,5))
```

I made a function that returns the `rowMeans` for the columns of the 'data' df that make up an area according to the 'index' df

```
myfun <- function (curr.target) {
       target.cols <- as.character(index$name[index$area==curr.target])
        return(rowMeans(data[target.cols],na.rm=T))
    }
```

I then use the function to get row means for areas by looping through the areas.

```
for (i in seq_along(unique(index$area))){
  data[,as.character(unique(index$area))[i]] <- myfun(as.character(unique(index$area))[i])
}
```

I'm beating myself trying to think of how to do this in one line (once the function is written) but just can't put my finger on it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please use `set.seed` to make this reproducible as `sample` was used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `split` the 'name' column in 'index' by 'area', then loop through the `list`, subset the 'data' based on the 'name' column in 'index' and get the `rowMeans`

```
sapply(split(as.character(index$name), index$area), function(x) rowMeans(data[x]))
```

Comment: Thanks for that @akrun, `split` will be of great use and I've not come up against it before. Is there a way that I can manipulate the columns names of the output within that call? Specifically reordering columns according to another index, and/or making the colnames uppercase using `toupper()`?

Comment: @Alex  Then, you need to `loop` through the sequence of the `split` i.e. `lst <- split(as.character(index$name), index$area); lapply(seq_along(lst), function(i) ...)` I am not entirely sure what you are up to.

Answer (score 2):

Use sapply() and `cbind()` like this:

```
uia <- unique(index$area)
cbind(data, sapply(uia, myfun))
```

The results:

```
  name1 name2 name3 name4 name5 name6 area1    area2 area4 area5
1     5    10    10     6     8     9   8.2 6.666667     6     8
2     7     9     2     4    10     1   5.6 6.000000     4    10
3     8     1     8     8     4     2   3.4 6.666667     8     4
4     2     4     7     9     5     7   5.0 7.666667     9     5
5     3     7     1    10     1     4   3.8 7.000000    10     1
```